# Trouble registering a property in App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I apologize for my dumb question, but I've tried everything from the docs and it looks like I can't understand how it works.

I'm trying to set a simple property in `App.vue` and it gives me an error:

> Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render.

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Test',
    titleTemplate: '%s - Example'
  },
  test: 'Testing the properties'
}
</script>
```

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'

import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'

Vue.use(VueMeta)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply add `custom` properties to the components. Instead add `test` to [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods):

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  metaInfo: {
    title: 'Test',
    titleTemplate: '%s - Example'
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      test: 'Testing the properties'
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It gives me `Unexpected labeled statement` and `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`... ;-(

Comment: I updated the answer, please try the updated answer. thanks

Comment: Btw, can I set the `test` prop in `main.js`, so I can update it in the components differently?

Comment: Do you mean to update the component in a single location, such as top level parent, and react to that change in other components as child or nested child components?

Comment: For example, set `test` to "hello", and if needed, in Home.vue to change it to "world"?

Comment: Usually to communicate between components, you'd either have a shared parent component that pass down props and listens for emitted events from children to update shared props, or you can use something like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to manage a shared state in a centralized store.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it! I really appreciate your help! :-)